# Raw string: I would like to print "\"

Tags: python

**Python 3.5.2**

```
s = r'\'
print(s)

  File "/home/michael/workspace/regexp/regexp.py", line 1
    s = r'\'
           ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Could you help me understand why this expression leads to an error. If I add another symbol, say, `s = r'\\'`, no syntax error.

But I want just one slash.

Comment: Use `'\\'` (not a raw string literal).

Comment: That seems to be part of the question. Why not a raw string?

Comment: See the duplicate, you can't end a raw string literal in a backslash because both `\'` and `\"` still have special meaning in a raw string literal.

Comment: Thank you. My question really is a duplicate.